# Django - Display a ModelForm foreign key field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

### Model & Form

```
class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(User)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    widgets = {
      'author': forms.HiddenInput(),
    }
```

This book form doesn't allow changing the author

### Template

But I'd like to display his firstname

```
<form action="/books/edit" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.author.label }}: {{ form.author.select_related.first_name }}
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

### Question

Of course `form.author.select_related.first_name` doesn't work

How can I display the firstname of the author ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
<form action="/books/edit" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.author.label }}: {{ form.instance.author.first_name }}
  {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

But you cannot use this form for creating books, only for updating, this won't work if the author is not set on instance.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a read only field?

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.id:
            self.fields['author'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    def clean_author(self):
        return self.instance.author

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        widgets = {
           'author': forms.TextInput(),
        }
```

The `clean_author` method is there to prevent malicious requests trying to override the author.

Comment: It displays the id of the author