# In a form, How to display fields from other models using foreign keys, specially a field with choices?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, models, modelform

I am making a test form using `ModelForm` which has two models.

1. `Country`
2. `Email`

I am creating a form based on `Email` models.
The `Country` model has name field, with the values given by the `COUNTRIES` list.
I want to display name field in the `EmailForm`, with all the `COUNTRIES` values. Do I have to use a foreign key? Please guide.

My models look like this:

```
COUNTRIES = (('IND', 'India'), ('PAK', 'Pakistan'), ('AMR', 'America'))

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=COUNTRIES)

class Email(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    sender = models.EmailField(max_length=20)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class EmailForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
```

If I generate a form out of this. it shows a drop down menu which is blank. How to get values from the list?

Comment: possibly duplicated How do I add a Foreign Key Field to a ModelForm in Django? - Stack Overflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708650/how-do-i-add-a-foreign-key-field-to-a-modelform-in-django and in question like this add code too

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to add custom field to your ModelForm and exclude original foreign key:

```
class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    country_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        exclude = ('country',)
```

Then, in your view you should manualy create (or get if it exists) your company and save the form:

```
def foo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.country = Country.objects.get_or_create(cname=form.cleaned_data['country_name'])
            form.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I tried this code. It is giving drop down list but not actual values from clist. All the values are replaced by 'Country Object'.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. In this example you should write {{form.country_name}} not {{form.country}}

Comment: I did this:
'class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name'

Comment: So whenever I have to call a ForeignKey, names of countries will directly appear from Country table, though importing Countries to table will be a added task.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer maybe in this post [Django - Display a ModelForm foreign key field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332514/django-display-a-modelform-foreign-key-field)

However, I haven't been able to successfully make it work yet.